# Largest + second largest number in C

Tags: c, loops, sum, max, calculation

please help me.
What's wrong with my code? my code doesnt work at third sample case and some other numbers?

Problem :

Format Input
Input starts with an integer T, describing the number of test cases. Each test case starts with an integer N, the number of boxes that Lili has. The next line will contain N numbers Vi, each of them describe the value of the coin in the i-th box. It is guaranteed that the value will always be between -1000000 and 1000000.

Format Output
For each test case, output a single line consisting of ”Case #X: Y” where X is the test case number and Y is the maximum value Lili can get by choosing exactly 2 boxes.

Constraints

•1 ≤ T ≤ 10

• 2 ≤ N ≤ 1, 000, 000

• −1, 000, 000 ≤ Vi ≤ 1, 000, 000

Sample Input (standard input)

3

5

1 2 3 4 5

4

4 4 4 4

3

10 1 2

Sample Output (standard output)

Case #1: 9

Case #2: 8

Case #3: 12

*So, this problem want to sum the first and second maximum number

*Idk why my code doesn't work at third sample case and some number it sums it up to 20 please help

This is what i've written so far

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int t;
long int n, max1, max2, v[100];

scanf("%d", &t);

for(int i=1; i<=t; i++){
  if(t>=1 && t<=10){

  scanf("%ld", &n);}

    if(n>=2 && n<=1000000){
        for(long int j=0; j<n; j++){
        scanf("%ld", &v[j]);
        }

        max1 = v[0];
          for(long int j=0; j<n; j++){
            if(max1<v[j]){
              max1=v[j];
            }
          }
        max2 = v[0];
          for(long int j=0; j<n; j++){
            if(v[j]!=max1 && v[j]>max2){
              max2=v[j];
            }
          }

            long int sum=max1+max2;
            printf("Case #%d: ", i);
            printf("%ld\n", sum);
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Idk why my code doesn't work". The way to find out is to debug the code. Run your code in a debugger and step through it line by line to examine what it is doing and find where things don't behave as expected.

Comment: Alright i will try debugging my code thank youu :)

Comment: Read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), and the documentation of your debugger (maybe [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Comment: If N is actually the maximum of 1 million, are you still going to try to read into an array with 100 entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for finding `max2` is wrong for a number of reasons. You do:

```
if(v[j]!=max1 && v[j]>max2){
```

Consider what happen for data like "1 5 5". First you'll find `max1` to be 5. Then due to the `v[j]!=max1` you never set `max2` to 5 so it'll stay on the value 1.

Try a single loop:

```
// max1 shall be the largest of the first two numbers
// max2 shall be the smallest of the first two numbers
if (v[0] > v[1])
{
    max1 = v[0];
    max2 = v[1];
}
else
{
    max1 = v[1];
    max2 = v[0];
}

// Start the loop from the third element
for(long int j=2; j<n; j++)
{
    if (v[j] > max1)
    {
        // New maximum
        max2 = max1;
        max1 = v[j];
    }
    else if (v[j] > max2)
    {
        // New second highest number
        max2 = v[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Choutato notice that I just fixed a bug in the initialization part

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the statement `max2 = v[0];` For the sample case : 10 1 2, `max2=10`.
So no other values (1 2) are greather than 10. Hence the if condition `if(v[j]!=max1 && v[j]>max2)` is never satisfied in the third sample test case. `max2=10`

Solution: Assign `max2` with some negative number (Initially). I suggest you to use `INT_MIN`

PS: This change will not work for second sample test case.

Comment: Ohh i understand now! thank you so much this was very helpful!

Comment: @Choutato  This will not work for second sample test case (Same numbers case)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
max2 = v[0];
for(long int j=0; j<n; j++){
  if(v[j]!=max1 && v[j]>max2){
    max2=v[j];
  }
}
```

When the numbers are 10, 1, 2 you start with `max1 = 10` and `max2 = 10`. You then reject everything which is not max1 and less or equal to max2. That's 10 (equals max1), 1 (less than 10), and 2 (also less than 10). So you count 10 twice. You will always have this problem when the largest number is the first one.

A simple fix is to initialize `max2` to the smallest possible long integer, [`LONG_MIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#limits.h). Since there's always at least two numbers this is safe.

A better algorithm is to keep track of max1 and max2 together. And since we're doing it in a single pass there's no need to store the input. Use the same trick of initializing them to the smallest number.

It's also not necessary to use `long int`; while by the standard an `int` can be as small as 16 bits, unless you're working in some advanced environments it is at least 32 bits.

```
#include<limits.h>
...

    for(int i=1; i<=t; i++){
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);

        // Initialize our maxes to the smallest possible integer.
        // Everything will be equal or larger.
        int max[2] = {INT_MIN};
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            int input;
            scanf("%d", &input);

            // The input is larger than max[0]
            if( input > max[0] ) {
                // Make the largest the second largest.
                max[1] = max[0];
                // Make the input the new largest number.
                max[0] = input;
            // The input is smaller than max[0], but larger than max[1].
            } else if( input > max[1] ) {
                // Make the input the new second largest.
                max[1] = input;
            }
        }

        printf("Case #%d: ", i);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", max[0], max[1], max[0] + max[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Ohh okay i understand the logic now! thank you very muchh! :D